# Flipping texture when copying to another texture

Tags: opengl

I need to flip my texture vertically when copying it into another texture.I know about 3 simple ways to do it:

1 . Blit from once FBO into another using full screen quad (and flip in frag shader)

2 . Blit using [glBlitFrameBuffer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBlitFramebuffer.xml).

3 . Using  [glCopyImageSubData](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCopyImageSubData.xml)

I need to perform this copy between 2 textures which aren't attached to any FBO so I am trying to avoid first 2 solutions.I am trying the third one.

Doing it like this:

```
glCopyImageSubData(srcTex ,GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,0,targetTex,GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,width ,0,height,0,1);
```

It doesn't work.The copy returns garbage.Is this method supposed to be able to flip when reading?Is there an alternative FBO unrelated method(GPU side only)?

Btw:

```
glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,0,height ,width,0 );
```

Doesn't work too.

Comment: Your resulting copyable width=0, so it shouldn't copy anything at all. But anyway, `glCopyImageSubData` is just GPU-side `memcpy`, it doesn't perform any conversion. I see using shaders (or just flipping texture coordinates) as only option.

Comment: Upload another with a `invert-y` flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rendering a textured quad to a pbo by drawing the inverted quad would work.

Or you could go with a simple fragment shader doing a imageLoad + imageStore by inverting the y coordinate with 2 bound image buffers.

```
glBindImageTexture(0, copyFrom, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_ONLY, GL_RGBAUI32);        
glBindImageTexture(1, copyTo, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBAUI32);
```

the shader would look something like:

```
layout(binding = 0, rbga32ui) uniform uimage2d input_buffer;
layout(binding = 1, rbga32ui) uniform uimage2d output_buffer;
uniform float u_texHeight;
void main(void)
{
    vec4 color = imageLoad( input_buffer, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy) );
    imageStore( output_buffer, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.x,u_texHeight-gl_FragCoord.y-1), color );
}
```

You'll have to tweak it a little, but I know it works I used it before.

Hope this helps